# Spring MVC - Throws exception when the int value of ModelAttribute is null

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404, modelattribute

I'm building an web application using Spring 3.0 MVC.

I have a method which has prototype below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/blahblah/blah.do", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public void searchData(@RequestParam(value="uniqOid", required=false) String uniqOid, @ModelAttribute("MasterVo") MasterVo searchVo,
          ModelMap model, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)
```

The problem is that, the view (jsp) contains `input`s that matches to `searchVo(ModelAttribute)`.
When the int or long value of `searchVo` didn't come from the jsp, the server throws 404 page not found exception.

If the type of value is "String", it has no problem.

In my opinion, it is the problem of type casting.

How could I solve this problem, and which part of the server code that I have to check?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some of your JSP code and the `searchData` method body. Also the end of your method params are not code formatted.

Comment: Post your stacktrace, and the part of `MasterVo` that contains the problematic field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will go ahead and assume a few things about your problem.

It is not a `type-cast` problem. Spring has default converters that can easily convert from a `String` to some primitive type.

Now what you are facing is I think a `null assigment to primitive type` problem. Suppose the name of the `property` that's causing the problem is named `primitiveProperty`. Now, the request-paramters could include a parameter named `primitiveProperty` with an empty-String value, or some value that cannot be converted to a number. If the type of the `primitiveProperty` is String, it can assign the value of that parameter to it without any problem.

If the type of the `primitiveProperty` is `int`, `long` or some other primitive type that cannot have a `null` value, a problem occurs. When Spring converts the empty-string or a non-numeric string valued request-param named `primitiveProperty`, it cannot do so since that string can't be converted to a valid `int` or `long` value. So it is converted to null. Now, when Spring tries to assign that null value to a property that cannot have a `null` value (any primitve type), you get an `Exception`. If you are getting an empty-string as your request-param, you can replace the troublesome property in your domain object with its equivalent `wrapper class` (`int` with `Integer`, `long` with `Long` and so on). If you are getting a non-numeric value from your view, well, make sure that you don't get a non-numeric value.

Comment: Thank you very much Bhashit Parikh.
I solved this problem by changing primitive types like int, long, float to Integer, Long, Float.

Thanks again.

Comment: Good answer and explanation...it saved my time..thanku

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the setter of the fields that are giving the typecast problem, in your case **MasterVo** .

The Spring will call the setter of the property to bind the value, where i presume you will see the error coming.
Just add a debug point to this setter and you will see the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much hellojava.
I solved this problem by changing primitive types like int, long, float to Integer, Long, Float.

Thanks again.